# Multiprocessing processes don't start

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to make a process start, no matter what, it just fails to do so. This simple code doesn't work:

```
import multiprocessing



def function():
    print("function started")



function_process = multiprocessing.Process(target = function)
function_process.start()
function_process.join()
```

The output of this code is simply nothing. If I print `function_process` after this, it returns `<Process name='Process-1' pid=13432 parent=7564 stopped exitcode=0>`. Adding `if __name__ == "__main__"` does nothing. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$ python mp.py 
function started
```

Maybe the code you show is part of a larger program, and this code is never called?

This is the code:

```py
import multiprocessing

def function():
    print("function started")

function_process = multiprocessing.Process(target = function)
function_process.start()
function_process.join()
```

Some IDEs redirect `STDIN`, `STDERR` and `STDOUT`, and data gets lost. The problem does not happen with Visual Studio Code or PyCharm.

Comment: I just ran it again, nothing happened :(

Comment: If you run the code I show, which is copied from your code, you should get the results I show, which is what you want.

Comment: Also if I copy and paste exactly what you said then nothing changes, still no output.

Comment: Go ahead. Copy/paste my code into a file called `mp.py` and run it with `python my.py`. You will get the output I show, which is what you want.

Comment: Where are you running this code? From a command line? An IDE? Online somewhere? Please run this from a command line exactly as described.

Comment: Nope, no change. I even created a new file with the same name and still got the same result: none.

Comment: I tried it online and it works. Please try for yourself at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: I ran it in Python IDLE, can I not do that? If I run it in a command line like you just told me to it runs just fine. Also if you add that to your answer then I'll mark it as an answer to help everyone else with my problem.

Comment: Which Python shell?

Comment: Sorry, I meant IDLE, got mixed up.

Comment: Python version 3.9.0

Comment: I never used IDLE, but some IDEs redirect STDIN, STDERR and STDOUT and data gets lost. The problem does not happen with Visual Studio Code or PyCharm.

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know. If you decide to edit your answer with this I'll happily give you the answer for my question.

Comment: I added the information to my answer as requested.

Comment: Your answer has been marked as the answer that solved my issue, thank you!